# Basic Auth header not sent on Angular GET request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I have a Spring Boot Angular application with Basic Auth security.
When I open the URL in the browser, the native browser Basic Auth window prompt is displayed where I can enter the Basic Auth information.

The problem is that the browser does not send the Basic Auth information to the backend with the GET-Request.

Can anyone explain why the basic auth info from the browser is not sent?

**General Request info**

```
Request URL: https://127.0.1.1:31000/my-application/rest/profile/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: 127.0.1.1:31000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Request headers**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.1.1:31000
Referer: https://127.0.1.1:31000/my-application/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/72.0.3626.121 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
```

**Response headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
connection: close
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 07:51:49 GMT
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
transfer-encoding: chunked
x-content-type-options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

**Angular Service that is used**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProfileDTO } from './profile-dto';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const profilesUrl = './rest/profile/';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfilService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    fetchAllProfiles(): Observable<ProfileDTO[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get<ProfileDTO[]>(profilesUrl);
    }
 }
```

**EDIT**

The problem is not that I can't get the reponse headers, the problem is that the Authorization header is not sent with the request.

I could send the basic auth info with the request for example with a interceptor:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ='}
        });
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

With the interceptor everything works fine. The authorization header is sent to the backend.

But the problem is that I don't know how to get the basic auth info from the native browser basic auth prompt.

Can anyone tell me how to get the basic auth info from the browser basic auth prompt?

I actually thought that the Authorization Header is added by the browser...

Comment: Did you explicitly set the authentication keys/info on your headers? You can either do so on your service file, or on your interceptor. Let me know if you need any help on that..!

Comment: no. I know how to set the headers, but I don't know how to get the basic auth info from the browser. how can i get the basic auth info from the browser?

Comment: Oh, ok, just to clarify, are you trying to get the information on your request headers?

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate for another one I have already answered to : I will let you try the answer in this question, and if it doesn't wotk, please post another question with a [mcve] and a detailed description of the issue you're facing (stating that you already tried to expose the headers)

Comment: hmmm. the question you that you provided as duplicate has nothing to do with my question in my opinion...

Comment: @trichetriche I edited the question and explain why it is not a duplicate as the one you provided as answer

Comment: @LorenzPfisterer I see, then you should create another question on how to deal with Basic Auth security. I don't think your issue is with Angular, since you do not seem to encounter any issue with the framework itself, but with an authentication framework/library.

Comment: @trichetriche the problem only occurs with angular HttpClientModule. When I use native javascript the basic auth header is provided by the browser. So it is an angular question...

Comment: I didn't mean it isn't an Angular question, I meant that because of what you said ("I don't know how to get the basic auth info from the native browser basic auth prompt"), you should rewrite your question to focus on that. am I mistaken ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic Auth is shaped using username/email and password, that depending on server credential.
you can trying like this

```
const basicAuth = username + ':' + password;
let Headers = new HttpHeaders();
Headers = Headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(basicAuth));
return this.dataService.post<any>(URL, null, { headers: Headers })...
```

Answer (score -1):

**simple service send header**

export class ProfilService {
            constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

```
fetchAllProfiles(token): Observable<ProfileDTO[]> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

            return this._httpClient.get('your-api', {params: httpParams, headers: headers})
          .map((response: ProfileDTO[]) => response);
      }
```

}
}

Comment: I use basic auth and not a token. the basic auth info I enter to the native browser basic auth prompt

Comment: you have to get info and send as header

Comment: how can I get the info from the browser?